# Cannot open COM port in several applications

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am trying to connect an U-blox C94-M8P development board to my PC in order to process its GNSS data stream. In the device manager, it says that the board is connected to `"u-blox virtual COM Port(COM19)"`. When I use the u-blox software to connect the board, all works fine and it is connected. Though when I try to connect it via another application all programs say `"Cannot open serial port COM19"`or Windows errorcode `2`.

My C++ code to establish the connection looks like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Serial.h"

    int main()
    {
        Serial serial;
        std::string port = "\\.\COM19";
        const char *portaddress=port.data();
        std::cout<<serial.Open(portaddress,9600);


        return 0;
    }
```

and Serial.cpp like this:

```
int Serial::Open(const char* port, int baudrate) {

    // if connected: close current connection before opening a new one
    if(m_SerialHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        Close();
    }

    TCHAR vibroTacPort[15];
    sprintf(vibroTacPort, "\\\\.\\%s", port);

    // Open serial port
    m_SerialHandle = CreateFile(vibroTacPort, // port // "\\\\.\\COM13"
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                0,//FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, // | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);

    // FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED is necessary for event-driven communication, Handle hast to be flagged for overlapped IO, otherwise Serial::Request() blocks if no event occurs (e.g. if the VibroTac device does not respond to the request)
    // FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING increase the system performance
    // Note: FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH is not be supported by all hard disks
    // (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior)


    if(m_SerialHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        //  Handle the error.
        switch(errorCode) {
        case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
        case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
            //  121     The semaphore timeout period has expired.
            //  1167    The device is not connected.
            // fall through and do nothing for now
            ;
        }
        return (errorCode);
    }

    // Do some basic settings
    DCB serialParams = { 0 };
    serialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(serialParams);

    if (!GetCommState(m_SerialHandle, &serialParams)) {
        Close();
        return ERROR_OPEN_FAILED;
    };
    serialParams.BaudRate = baudrate;
    serialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    serialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (!SetCommState(m_SerialHandle, &serialParams)) {
        Close();
        return ERROR_OPEN_FAILED;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this? I closed the u-blox software, so nothing should be using the COM Port when I try to access it...

The other software I try to use the serial connection with is `"BKG NTRIP Client"`

Additional Info: in the properties it says `"Connected : <true>"`.

Comment: After you close the u-blox software, does this virtual comport still exist? Assuming you use windows, you can find this in My Computer -> Properties -> Device Manager

Comment: Yes, it even continues existing when the device is not connected.

Comment: I tried to restart my computer, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: In that case, the problem might be within the driver software. First, see if you can connect to your device using com-terminal software like realterm. If that doesn't work, you know the problem is not in your code.

Comment: Using PuTTY I get the right NMEA output. So the problem has to be in my C++ code (there I tried to connect another serial device and it failed, too, so I am pretty sure that my code is faulty). But what about the BKG software? I guess it should be ok, so why can't I connect with this software?

Comment: There is an obvious bug in the way you name the port.  You use backslashes correctly in the Open() function but then you do it *again*, incorrectly, in main().  Fix: `std::string port = "COM19";`  Fwiw: never hard-code a port name, it will never repeat from one machine to another.  Use Device Manager to verify which port numbers are available.

Comment: Thanks for this fix @Hans, now I get `0` as return value, meaning it works (even with the development board) :)